# Converting an integral equation into a differential equation .

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, optimal-control

Let $a, b \in \mathbb R^n$ and $f, g \in L^1 [0,1]$. Assume for all $h \in AC[0,1 ]$ (space of absolutely continuous functions) following integral equality holds

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \langle f(t) , h(t) \rangle \; dt +  \int_{0}^{1}  \langle g(t) , h' (t) \rangle  \; dt + \langle h(0) , a \rangle + \langle h(1) , b \rangle  = 0        $$

My question : Can we simplify the above expression more? In the sense above can be equivalently written in the form of an ODE in terms of $f,g,a,b$?

Note that all functions are from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^n$. However we can assume they are just real valued function for simplicity. I was thinking about trying $h = \text{constant or exponential functions.}$

Comment: Isn't this an equality instead of an inequality? Also how do you define the inner product between a scalar and a vector?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Thanks. I  edit it right now

Comment: It looks pretty much as [du Bois-Raymond lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations). Since $f$, $g$ are just $L^1$, I guess, you will get ODE in the sense of distributions. Maybe [weak derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative) are enough.

Comment: crossposted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/341435/85967

Comment: @A.Γ. I guess you are right. Can you please provide a short/brief  detail. I'm not familiar with weak derivatives and ODE in the sense of distribution, but they look to me useful here

Comment: For $n = 1$, supposing $f$ is continuous and $g$ is differentiable and just looking at $h$ with $h(0) = h(1) = 0$, gives $\int_0^1 (f(t) - g'(t))h(t)dt = 0$, which gives $f - g' = 0$ on $(0,1)$.